# mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system

Tags: mount

I have a raspberry pi Zero W and a raspberry pi 3 both with a lite raspbian jessie image.
I am trying to connect them both to the same NFS share and I get this error:

```
pi@studypi:/mnt $ sudo mount //Imola/backup /mnt/backup -o user=Giles
Password for Giles@//Imola/backup:  ***************
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

on the raspberry pi 3.
The other pi works fine.
They both have `cifs-utils` installed and are the same version.
Both pis were installed from the same image file and both have been updated and upgraded.

Any ideas why one connects and the other doesn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

have you rebooted your Pi after installing the utils? I had the same issue with my fstab file and it got resolved with a reboot of my Pi.

Comment: I didn't install the utils, they were already installed with the OS image

Comment: Fixed my problem